# C# Application autorun exception

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, exception, autorun

I wanted to add my C# application to Windows autorun programmatically and read somewhere that code below would do the trick:

```
var key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
key.SetValue("MyApplication", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
```

When I restarted my computer, application's splash screen showed up but after a few seconds the application crashed and I saw this:

```
an unhandled microsoft .net framework exception occured
```

Could you give me some clues where to look for source of the problem?

**EDIT :**
I ran debugger and that's what I found out (XamlParseException):

```
{"'The invocation of the constructor on type 'MyApplication.GUI.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '3' and line position '9'."}
```

And inner exception message (System.UnauthorizedAccessException):

```
{"Access to the path 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\db.db' is denied."}
```

Comment: Did you check the Event Viewer to see if any information about the error was logged?

Comment: That is the correct code, maybe you don't have admin privileges? Try putting a try/catch around it and check the inner exception.

Comment: Can you post the Stack Trace so we can see the depth of the exception. That one line will not help by itself.

Comment: Do you access a file `'C:\\Windows\\system32\\db.db'` in your main form?

Comment: seems like your app needs access rights to the specified path. if I were you, I wouldn't be writing or reading from the system32 folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in your code, you are using a relative filename instead of a full path.  In other words, `"db.db"` instead of `"c:\foo\bar\db.db"`.  You'll now have a big dependency on the default directory of the program.  This will work just fine in Visual Studio when you debug and test your app, the default directory will be the bin\debug directory of your project.  You'll have no trouble writing to that directory.

But will *not* work when your program is launched by Windows, the default directory of your program will now be the default Windows directory, c:\windows\system32.  Programs do not have write access to that directory, it is protected by UAC.

Fix the bug by specifying the full path to the file.  You'll want to use Environment.GetFolderPath() to obtain a good directory, that should almost always be `SpecialFolder.ApplicationData`.  Use the Path.Combine() helper method to construct the path.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer.